# How to show a git message body (not just the title)?

Tags: git, git-log, git-show

I've been doing a fair amount of research and can't find this trivial functionality:

`git log` and `git show` are only showing the headline/title of the commit message, but I'd like to see the rest of the body.

By body, I mean the section where 'conflicts' and 'squashed commits' are usually listed.

How can I view this information?

Thanks

Comment: I might have misunderstood you. When you create a commit, the Git-supplied template includes comments that, with default options, won't be included in the resulting commit message.  To include them, you can either strip the comment leader (a leading `#` character cause git to ordinarily strip that line from the resulting message) or supply [an alternate message-cleanup option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---cleanupltmodegt).Is this what you meant?

Comment: @jthill This is exactly the issue, I'm kinda embarrassed/not sure how to make this question helpful for people. Maybe an answer about enabling that by default could be useful. I assumed that section was similar to direct README.md commits on github where there's a body section, or I guess merges that I've seen include that by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a commit, the Git-supplied template includes comments that, with default options, won't be included in the resulting commit message.

To include them, you can either strip the comment leader (a leading # character cause git to ordinarily strip that line from the resulting message) or supply [an alternate message-cleanup option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---cleanupltmodegt).

```
:%s,^#,,
```

is the vim command to strip the comment leaders.

Answer (score 0):

After you squashed, actually you can't see the deleted commits. But I think it'll be a useful "git reflog" command. It shows the path of your head had been with hash codes.[my experience in above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBP6i.png)